# is 2nd criterion of inference satisfied for the restrictions on rules governing quantifiers

Tags: logic

[image]

these two criteria are mentioned in patrick suppes book- intro to logic.

then to account for criterion 1 , some rules of restrictions on quantifiers are given.
But about criterion 2, how do we know these rules are enough ?

Comment: The 2nd Criterion is satisfied with the **Completeness Theorem**.

Comment: See Suppes, page 23 : "Criterion I says that the rules of inference must be *sound*".

Comment: See Suppes, page 24 : "Criterion II says that the rules of inference must be *complete*".

Comment: i have not yet read about Completeness Theorem, but will this prove all conclusions can be derived?

Comment: Yes; for proof systems that are *complete*, i.e. for which a *Completeness Th* does hold, this means that all conclusions that follow logically from the premises are derivable (with the rules of the proof system) from the premises.